# How to center text with a background image

Tags: css

I really would like to do something like this...it's for when I have text with icons on the left:

[image]

I tried (unsuccessfully) to do something along the lines of:

```
    <a href="#" class="icon">Text centered vertically in relation 
to the background image</a>
```

CSS

```
a.icon {
background: url(image.png) 0 50%;
margin-top: -5%;
min-height: the-height-of-my-image-plus-the-negative-margin;
}
```

Comment: can you post a link to an image of what you're getting with the above?

Comment: It's more of a general thing...any image with any text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give `line-height` same as `height` of your `a` tag. Like this:

```
a.icon {
background: url(image.png) 0 50%;
margin-top: -5%;
height:40px;
line-height:40px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a.icon {
background: url(image.png) 0 50%;
padding: ?px ?px
}
```

Adjust the padding ?px

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a perfect solution, but the following code may work. However, it breaks anchors-links spec, and it's a very bad practice.

### CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
.fixinline {
 display: inline-block;
}
.icon { 
 background: red url(http://goo.gl/12gdn) no-repeat left center;
 height: 135px; /* >= image height */
 display: table;
 padding: 0 0 0 135px; /* >= image height */
}
.icon span {
 display: table-cell;
 background-color: yellow;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
```

### HTML

```
<span class="fixinline"><a class="icon"><span>hello<br>there</span></a></span>
```

​
[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brKr4/1/)